# Conditionally set single WiX Property to different values

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have an installer that deploys a website as either a SSL or non-SSL IIS site depending on whether a property is set or not. I've been asked to add the option to set the port, which isn't a problem, but I'd like to set the port to the default values (80 or 443) if the value isn't set.

I tried something like:

```
    <SetProperty Id="OUTPORT" Before="InstallFiles" Value="80"><![CDATA[SSL=0]]></SetProperty>
    <SetProperty Id="OUTPORT"  Before="InstallFiles" Value="443"><![CDATA[SSL=1]]></SetProperty>
```

But, obviously, WiX complains about the custom action having the duplicate ID SetOUTPORT.

Am I jumping down another WiX-shaped rabbit hole here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SetProperty now supports the Action attribute to let you specify custom action ids when you want to have multiple SetProperty elements for the same property with different conditions.

Comment: Perfect @Bob. When I first saw "CustomAction" I thought I was going to have to do the whole lot in managed code.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be valid (?any longer) http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_setproperty.htm

Answer (score 26):

The accepted answer is not correct in needing to convert to writing out in full the custom action and sequencing (no longer?).

As per documentation for WiX 3, [SetProperty Element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_setproperty.htm)

Without setting SetProperty\@Action

```
<SetProperty Id="OUTPORT" Before="InstallFiles" Value="80"><![CDATA[SSL=0]]></SetProperty>
<SetProperty Id="OUTPORT"  Before="InstallFiles" Value="443"><![CDATA[SSL=1]]></SetProperty>

Duplicate symbol 'CustomAction:SetInstallFiles' found
```

**Action**. *String*. By default, the action is "Set" + Id attribute's value. This optional attribute can override the action name in the case where multiple SetProperty elements target the same Id (probably with mutually exclusive conditions).

The following works without having to change to writing out custom actions.

```
<SetProperty Action="SetInstallFiles0" Id="OUTPORT" Before="InstallFiles" Value="80"><![CDATA[SSL=0]]></SetProperty>
<SetProperty Action="SetInstallFiles1" Id="OUTPORT" Before="InstallFiles" Value="443"><![CDATA[SSL=1]]></SetProperty>
```

It works in WiX 3.7, and I am not sure about which first version it is available from.

Comment: Yes, SetProperty and SetDirectory were enhanced to support this scenario.

Comment: @Greg, I think it makes sense to edit original answer with this info for consistency.

Comment: It's really amazing!